# onPresssed of IconButton does not gets called inside a stack widget when overflow is Overflow.visible

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the following code

```
void showShortBioDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Dialog(
            child: Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 40),
                    child: Text(
                      "Short Bio",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: white, fontFamily: "BarlowBold"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: blue2,
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 30,
                  right: -5,
                  left: -5,
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    elevation: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 180,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: TextField(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: -170,
                  right: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("hi");
                    },
                    iconSize: 35,
                    icon: Image.asset(
                      "images/next_signup.webp",
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      height: 35,
                      width: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

The dialog looks properly as i want and the dialog gets triggered when screen appears. but the `iconbutton's` `onPressed` is never called
I tried replacing the icon button with a `InkWell`,`RaisedButton`,`FlatButton` etc but the `onPressed` is never called for that button.
The position of the icon button is also at the last in the stack but i am still confused why its on click is not called.

I want an output something like follow

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K12-Dw4xRzHNd9N1gM02TcHd6TdK319Y/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of overflowing. If you comment `overflow: Overflow.visible` then you won't be able to see the image at all. Try making the dialog big enough to have the image positioned on top without overflowing.

Comment: Will try and let you know

Comment: but i need the overflow property and i cant make the dialog more big because of design constraints from the designer

Comment: It is not necessary that you have to use dialog then. What is it that you want to do? You want your dialog to be big enough to show the image or not? Also, why are you using stack and not a column? Please make an image of how you want your dialog to look.

Comment: I want some thing like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K12-Dw4xRzHNd9N1gM02TcHd6TdK319Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried giving the button elevation with card but it didnt worked @KeertiPurwani

Comment: I tried adding FAB as well but it stops working as soon as it overflows the border. I don't think you can use dialog then, you will have to make your own widget using decorated box referring the dialog code.

Comment: Ya i was also trying use FAB. Thanks for the suggestion and your time

Comment: Let me know if you are able to do it :)

Comment: yeah sure will let you know

Comment: Could you create the widget?

Comment: No not yet sorry, i am still figuring  it out